Fixed non-trivial ideal classes of $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p]$ over $\mathbf{Z}$ under the action of the Galois group
Can a non-trivial ideal class (i.e., an ideal class different from the class of principal ideals) of $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p]$ where $p$ is prime, be fixed under the action of the Galois group (when considering $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_p]$ over $\mathbf{Z}$)?

Suppose that $I^{\sigma} = I$. Let $q$ and write $q = \prod \mathfrak{q}_i$ if $q \ne p$. The Galois group acts transitively on the primes above $q$, so if $I$ is exactly divisible by $\mathfrak{q}^r_i$ then it is exactly divisible by $\mathfrak{q}^r_j$ for all $j$. It follows that $I$ is principal since the factors above $q \ne p$ combine to give $(q^r)$, whereas the unique prime above $p$ is $(1-\zeta_p)$ is already principal.

@user523984 Your argument seems to assume the ideal itself is fixed, rather than just the class.

@WillSawin, The other version is also true! Let $K=\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)$. $C=\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q})$ is cyclic. If $M=\mathrm{Cl}(K)$ then $M^C \ne 1$ implies $M_C \ne 1$ (since $C$ is cyclic they have the same order). Let $H/K/\mathbf{Q}$ be (from CFT) the everywhere unramified extension with Galois group $M_C$ over $K$; $G = \mathrm{Gal}(H/\mathbf{Q})$ is an extension of $C$ by $M_C$. Inertia at $p$ gives a splitting $C \rightarrow G$; since the action of $C$ on $M_C$ is trivial, $G$ is abelian. But Kronecker-Weber implies $K$ has no unramified extensions abelian over $\mathbf{Q}$.

The question is if an ideal class different from the trivial one can be fixed by the action of the Galois group. Another way to ask it is if an ideal class is fixed by the Galois group it must be the trivial ideal class (the ideal class of principal ideals). If someone could also give me some reference for it (if there is), it would be very helpful.

Well I gave you a full proof of that version in the comment above. It's not like every random statement has a reference,

@user491858 I think your very interesting comments could be an answer!

Yes sorry, I am a student and I don't fully understand everything, so if you have some reference of any related book that defines all the concepts used and all the notation used in the answer I would really appreciate it.

A different way to say the same proof with references (but harder). Let $L=\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)$, $K=\mathbf{Q}$. $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is cyclic of degree $n$ generated by $g$. The ambiguous class number formula (Ex 5 here: https://shorturl.at/4Pemw) says
$$|\mathrm{Cl}(L)^{g=1}|=\frac{|\mathrm{Cl}(K)|\prod_v e_v}{n[\mathcal{O}^{\times}K:\mathcal{O}^{\times}K\cap N{L/K}(L^{\times})]}$$
You are asking if this is trivial. Since $K$ is $\mathbf{Q}$ the class number is $1$. $e_p=n$ and $e{\infty}=2$. The unit group of $K$ is $\pm 1$ but norms here are positive. So it specializes to $2n/2n=1$.

@Olivier the real art is crafting a complete solution which fits into the character limit of a comment. That is what pleases me.

@user491858 If you could find a truly marvelously crafted such solution proving that it is impossible to separate a cube in the sum of two cubes or a quadratic quadratic in the sum of two quadratic quadratic and in general any power higher of two in two such, that would be very neat.
